# Phonegap : What happens to my sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am using phonegap for my mobile application. I am creating a database from the application.
Everything is working fine and as expected.

But what happens to my database when I uninstall my application?
The database is also removed or do I have to remove the database manually?

I have created a different app to erase the database, but looking at the `console.log()`s it is seen that database also gets erased along with the application.

Is it true? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you deinstall the App like the user would by deleting the App on the Telephone, the Data of Database also gets deleted.
When I re-install the App for Developing, let`s say with

```
./adb install <packagename>
```

or from XCode, the Data does **not** get deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your response buddy. When the app starts, every time I am checking if the table exists, if not, then I will create it and populate it with the default data.
I have `console.log()`-ed where the control goes. When I re-run the app, it shows the data. When I uninstall it and reinstall it, then the data seems to be lost. I was just wondering if it the default behavior or am I doing something wrong.